# Determining coefficients of a solution to a system of differential equations without initial conditions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, physics, wave-equation

I am trying to find a solution to a system of the following two differential equations:

$$\frac{\partial^2 B}{\partial x^2} = -(\mu_0 \epsilon_0)^2 \frac{\partial^2 B}{\partial t^2}\tag1$$
$$\frac{\partial^2 E}{\partial x^2} = \mu_0 \epsilon_0 \frac{\partial^2 B}{\partial t^2}\tag2$$

(To some of those who know physics, these equations may seem erroneous, but that is intentional.)
Now, by noting that the general solution to the wave equation given by $(1)$ is of the form 
$$B(x,t) = F\left(x-\frac{it}{\mu_0 \epsilon_0}\right)+G\left(x+\frac{it}{\mu_0 \epsilon_0}\right)$$ 
and by using Euler's identity and the principle of superposition, I obtained the following solution for $B(x,t)$:

$$B = e^{-x}f(t)+e^{-\frac{t}{\mu_0 \epsilon_0}} g(x)$$

where

$$f(t) = C_1 \cos \left(\frac{t}{\mu_0 \epsilon_0}\right) + C_2 \sin \left(\frac{t}{\mu_0 \epsilon_0}\right)\\ 
g(x) = C_3 \cos x + C_4 \sin x$$

and $C_i$ are arbitrary constants. It follows by equation $(2)$ that

$$E = -\frac{1}{\mu_0 \epsilon_0} B$$

I was told that these solutions are almost correct, but apparently plugging my solutions back into "equations for E and B" (I am not certain whether these really refer to the differential equations) will give me some information about $C_1,C_2,C_3,C_4$. However, obviously, plugging the solutions into the differential equations simply gives me identities and no new information. The only ways I can think of to determine relationships of the coefficients are initial or boundary conditions, but there is none for this problem.
Are there any other ways to determine relationships for the coefficients? Thank you very much.

P.S. In case this helps, below are equations available for me to use to solve this problem, if necessary (but they may be useless in one-dimensional space):

$$\mathbf{\nabla} \cdot \mathbf{E} = 0\\ 
\mathbf{\nabla} \cdot \mathbf{B} = 0\\ 
\mathbf{\nabla} \times \mathbf{E} = - \frac{\partial \mathbf{B}}{\partial t}\\  
\mathbf{\nabla} \times \mathbf{B} = \mu_0 \epsilon_0 \frac{\partial \mathbf{B}}{\partial t}$$

(Once again, anything that seems incorrect in the above list is intentional.)

**[Edited 09/05/2018]**
It turned out that my solution was actually complete and it was my supervisor's misunderstanding that more information about the constants were to be obtained. I thank those who shared their ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you noticed, the first equation is the wave equation, so take the [general solution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave_equation#General_solution) of that for $B$.  The solutions you gave were not the most general.  And then $$\dfrac{\partial^2 E}{\partial x^2} = -\frac{1}{\mu_0 \epsilon_0} \dfrac{\partial^2 B}{\partial x^2}$$
implies $$ E = - \frac{B}{\mu_0 \epsilon_0}  + a(t) x + b(t) $$
where $a$ and $b$ are arbitrary functions of $t$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Actually, what I am asked to find is not the most general solution. I need solutions that have a nature of sinusoidal oscillation both in x and in t. With this requirement, I was told that the form of my solutions are correct and that I need to find some more information about the constants C1, C2, C3, and C4.

Comment: There is no such information (unless there's some other requirement you're not telling us about).  Your solutions are solutions of the differential equation for arbitrary values of the constants.

Comment: But perhaps you should look at solutions such as $\exp(b \mu_0 \epsilon_0 x + a t) \cos(a \mu_0 \epsilon_0 x - b t+c)$.

Comment: Yes, "there is no such information" is exactly what I thought, hence my confusion. Perhaps "there's some other requirement" that I am not aware of.

Comment: @Lefteris Are you sure that there are no other boundary conditions? Where did you get the equation from?

Comment: @Andrei Upon pointing out to my supervisor that the constants are arbitrary unless there are initial or boundary conditions, I confirmed that my solution is actually what was expected. I have added this update to the original post. Thank you.